# Visual C# 2010 Express: Opening a design and designer tab for a new form in the application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a form hat can be opened from the main form. But I don't really want to try to do it without a design and designer tabs. The main form has them by default. I'm not completely familiar with MS Visual C# 2010 express...

How can I open a design and designer tabs for a new form in the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a new Form in your solution:

[image: Add new item]
[image: Add new form]

Then add the following code somewhere in *Form1.cs*:

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.Show();
```